# Web service retrieves Data from Server but Client can't access them

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, apache-axis

The server side code retrieves a value from the DB. But I'm unable to provide the value to the Client side. Please help me out.

**Server side code:**

```
public int result(int ss) throws Exception
{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        String host="jdbc:mysql://localhost/test";
        String username="root";
        String password="";
        Connection connect=DriverManager.getConnection(host,username,password);
        System.out.println("Works");
        Statement s =connect.createStatement();
        s.execute("select * from customer");
        ResultSet rs=s.getResultSet();
        while(rs.next())
        {
                ss=rs.getInt(1);
                System.out.println("Retrieved element is = " + ss);
        }
        return ss;
}
```

**Client Side Code:**

```
public class sam {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException {

        Sample1Stub stub = new Sample1Stub();
        Result method = new Result();
        method.getSs();
            ResultResponse response = stub.result(method);
        System.out.println(response.get_return());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> boolean execute(String sql)

Executes the given SQL statement, which may return multiple results. In some (uncommon) situations, a single SQL statement may return multiple result sets and/or update counts. Normally you can ignore this unless you are (1) executing a stored procedure that you know may return multiple results or (2) you are dynamically executing an unknown SQL string. 
The execute method executes an SQL statement and indicates the form of the first result. You must then use the methods getResultSet or getUpdateCount to retrieve the result, and getMoreResults to move to any subsequent result(s).

Executes the given SQL statement, which returns a single ResultSet object. 
Note:This method cannot be called on a PreparedStatement or CallableStatement.

> ResultSet executeQuery(String sql)

Executes the given SQL statement, which returns a single ResultSet object. 
Note:This method cannot be called on a PreparedStatement or CallableStatement.

> s.execute("select * from customer");

instead of it use

> s.executeQuery("select * from customer");

Comment: No the problem is, i retrieved the values from the DB in the server side using the console .later i created web service for the server side coding and tried accessing using the web service client in the client side of my coding ..But the Exception which i got is : Exception in thread "main" org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: unknown